# importing the module in python

Tags: python, python-import

I am learning Python and while studying modules two doubts came to my mind.

- **Doubt #1:**

  I know that module is just simply python file such as `filename.py`, but what is a sub-module in Python?
- **Doubt #2:**

  Consider the following three lines of code:

  ```
  import modulename
  from pkgname import modulename
  from pkgname import *
  ```

  Do all three statements use `__init__.py` (which is inside `pkgname` package) or only the third statement?

Comment: **1.** A submodule is a module inside a package. **2.** `pkgname/__init__.py` is used whenever you import `pkgname` or one of its submodules (that is, lines 2 and 3 of your example).

Comment: how a package can consists sub-module, i mean as i know a package can consists of either module or sub-package(dimply directory). but how sub-module ? please give me any example.

Comment: As the package itself is also a module (content defined in `__init__.py`) any module in that package can be considered a sub-module of that package/module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make things a bit more clearer about your second question.

---

When you do -

```
import packagename.modulename
```

or

```
from packagename import modulename
```

Python internally first imports `packagename` , and when I say python imports `packagename` , I mean it imports the `__init__.py` of that package , and then after that it imports `modulename` . This is the reason why when you do any of the above it imports the `__init__.py` .

---

When you do -

```
from packagename import *
```

Please note, this does not import `modulename` from packagename by default , this would only import the `__init__.py` from packagename , and all modules that you have listed in `__all__` list in `__init__.py` , if no modules are listed in that list, none would be imported. Example -

Lets say I have

```
shared
   -- __init__.py
   -- a.py
```

`__init__.py` looks like -

```
print("In Shared")
```

`a.py` look like -

```
print("In A")
```

Now when in the directory above `shared` ,and openning python, if you do -

```
from shared import *
```

It would print out -

```
In Shared
```

But if you change that code in `__init__.py` to -

```
print("In Shared")
__all__ = ['a']
```

And do the same import from same location, It would print out -

```
In Shared
In A
```

As you can see it only imports submodules that are defined in the `__all__` list.

---

Finally , when you do -

```
import modulename
```

Lets say you do that directly from within `packagename` , by changing the directory to it and openning python interactive interpreter there. At that time, you are not asking Python to import packagename for you, so it does not need to import packagename , and hence it does not import `__init__.py` .

Comment: Awesome reply dude, you always help me in the best possible way. Thanku dude once again.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful :)

Comment: No, I mean click on the tick mark , tick mark is for accepting the answers , up-button is for upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

As Andrea Corbellini says in the comment:

1. A submodule is a module inside a package. A Python package is simply a directory of Python module(s) that contains an `__init__.py` file.
2. `pkgname/__init__.py` is used whenever you import pkgname or one of its submodules (that is, lines 2 and 3 of your example). Your first example doesn't import any package or module of a package therefore it doesn't need to use `__init__.py` (Which can be empty)

If there are these files, and you are working on the same folder

```
./pkgname/__init__.py  # Submodule of pkgname package used on example 3) to import all the submodules
./pkgname/Asdf.py  # Submodule of pkgname package
./pkgname/modulename.py  # Submodule of pkgname package imported in example 2) using __init__.py
./modulname.py  # Module imported on example 1)
```

Comment: Thanku for replying.
My first doubt have got cleared.

But in case of my second doubt, as u said
Your first example doesn't import any package or **module of a package** therefore it doesn't need to use __init__.py (Which can be empty), but i think it is importing module(i.e. sub-module) then why it is not using init.py(as you said) ?

Comment: in case of 

**./modulname.py  # Module imported on example 1)**
 there would be a module called **./init.p**. While importing **./modulname.py** using import **import modulename** statement will it use **./init.p** ?

Comment: No, you don't need `__init__.py` to import `./modulname.py`. Check it